# How to assign a custom azure private dns zone to an azure managed service like Redis or a storage account?

Tags: azure, azure-private-link, azure-private-dns, azure-private-dns-zone

How to assign a custom azure private DNS zone to azure managed services like Redis or a storage account?

I have created a custom private DNS zone

```
'privatelink.blob.core.dev.windows.net'
```

But while creating a private endpoint with a storage account azure portal doesn't allow me to use my custom private DNS zone and makes me use the default private DNS zone

```
'privatelink.blob.core.windows.net'
```

This is how DNS configuration of two private DNS zones looks like.

My custom private DNS zone on DNS configuration page of Private endpoint

```
Configuration name                      FQDN            IP address         Subscription             Private DNS zone                          DNS zone group                                                                                                                                                  
privatelink_blob_core_dev_windows_net                                      Azure Dev subscription   privatelink.blob.core.dev.windows.net  default
```

Default private DNS zone parameters on DNS configuration page of private endpoint

```
Configuration name                      FQDN                                                  IP address         Subscription             Private DNS zone                   DNS zone group
privatelink_blob_core_windows_net                                                                                Azure Dev subscription   privatelink.blob.core.windows.net  default
                                       testsainstance12345.privatelink.blob.core.windows.net
                                                                                              10.0.0.4
```

So how can I select a custom private DNS zone while creating a private endpoint for a storage account or any managed azure service which supports creating a private endpoint and make DNS resolution work between FQDN and private endpoint private IP address?